# How to replicate the ipod configuration screen in a iphone app?

Tags: iphone, configuration, uitabbar, ipod

I need to replicate the ipod configuration screen functionality, but have no idea how to do it.

Let me explain :

My App has several viewControllers, but only 5 are shown.
When the user hits the MORE tab, it will show all the available Views .
If he clicks on the EDIT button, the screen will show a bunch of tab-bar items, ( icon+title), which he can drag to the tabbar, and change it dynamically.

How can i accomplish this ?

My problem is not how to change the tabbar, but how to show the icons on the screen and (probably) use some drag'n'drop functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Apple did a nice job and provides this edit functionality for you already, check out the documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TabBarControllers/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH102-SW20

all the best,
Robin